# Add second title to Lightbox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ 
Currently my markup is like that:

```
<a href="path/to/img" 
data-lightbox="screenshots" 
data-title="<p class='gray-description'>This is image title</p>">
<img src="small-image.png">
</a>
```

It displays a title under image in lightbox. But now I need an option to add another one text in the top of lightbox. Is it possible to dynamically create element and append it to lightbox when it's loaded? I didn't find any callbacks in Lightbox 2 plugin options.

Comment: I have not used the lightbox but based on the html it outputs, you may try the following : $(".lb-nav")
.prepend("<div style='position:relative;top:5%;color:white'>Test</div>");

Comment: Yeah prepend works but no option to add new text when press prev/next buttons. Ended up putting 2 divs in data-title attribute and positioning one of them in the top using css.